# Change Pagination on Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add pagination using bootstrap 3, to the bottom of tables that exist within each tab. The script works for the first tab giving pagination but I cannot find a way for it to work with subsequent tabs. I have tried many things including unique names for myPager and myTable ids, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mzampogna/hbx58a09/4/

The problem is here(I'm sure there is some way to set up a call to it) -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',
      showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});


});

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the JS fiddle which solves the code and now we are able to see the pagination on both the tabs http://jsfiddle.net/6b0pjf1d/1/.

What needed to be added was just

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myTable1').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager1',
                       showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
});
```

And it worked. We need to page for all the tabs, as shown above, we need pagination for all of them. Hope this helps

Comment: That worked. Very simple solution. Hats off to you my friend!